# Getting the correct output when running through a while loop

Tags: python, loops, input, while-loop

```
 a = 1
 b = ""
 while a != b :
   a = float(input("enter value a: "))
   b = float(input("enter value b: "))
   if a == b:
     print("Thats correct") 
   elif a > b:
     print("a is higher")
   elif b > a:
     print("b is higher")
   else:
     print("not correct input, please try again"
```

How do i change the code so that if test the input value of a or b to be a string, the loop continues? The loop also needs to continue if the input values are the same but are both strings.

Comment: That's because `input` returns a string, so the "numbers" are ordered lexicographically.

Comment: Change `a=int(input("enter value b: "))` same for `b`